# Can you do typecasting in ML?

Tags: functional-programming, ml

I haven't done any programming in ML, but I am studying functional programming. ML is really particular about types in general, but I wanted to know if you could do typecasting to get around its strict type limitations? If you can't, is it because ML wants to lessen the chances of incorrect types, or is it something that just wasn't implemented?

Comment: Everything about ML is intentional. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Type casting" can mean a lot of different things. There are at least 3 completely different use cases:

- Converting between specific different types (e.g. numeric types). That is possible in ML through respective functions, they just aren't disguised as "casts"
- Casting back and forth from/to a top type (like `Object` or `void*`). This is just a hack to work around inexpressive type systems. Fortunately, ML has proper parametric polymorphism and algebraic datatypes, so doesn't normally need this.
- Doing nasty low-level trickery, subverting the type system completely. That is generally not supported in ML, since it is designed to be a safe, high-level language.

What form of type casting are you interested in in particular, and why?

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was talking about the first bullet point. I never really thought of the second bullet as type casting though. I was interested because I saw that you could have things like [1, 2, 3] in ML but you couldn't have [1, [1, 2], 3] (sorry if the syntax is off), because all of the elements of the second list are not of the same type. So, I thought about an example like [1, 2.0, 3]. Technically that won't work, but a cast could easily fix that.

Comment: @LearnLanguages96 Your examples are indistinguishable to ML; both fail because the second item in the list has a different type from the first—in the first example, it's an `int list`, in the second it's a `real`, but what's significant is that they don't match. SML is too pretty to permit such things in the standard, but there are implementation-specific casts, for instance, [in the Unsafe structure in SML/NJ](http://www.smlnj.org/doc/SMLofNJ/pages/unsafe.html) or [MLtonStructure  in MLton](http://mlton.org/MLtonStructure).

Comment: @LearnLanguages96, your example is about the second point. That's what you would usually use algebraic datatypes for. I assume your example is supposed to describe a tree, so you would define `datatype 'a tree = L of 'a | B of 'a tree list` and write it `B[L 1, B[L 1, L 2], L 3]`. Or if you truly want a heterogeneous list, then you can also use datatypes: `datatype item = N of int | S of string | B of bool  val xs = [N 5, B true, S "boo", N 6]`. Fortunately, the latter case is rarely needed in practice.

Comment: @DanielLyons, the Unsafe structures are rather intended to cover my third bullet point. You won't get far if you tried to use them to construct heterogeneous lists.